# Print lesser than/greater than sign inside a XML node as a value in python

Tags: python, xml

Trying to print lesser than/greater than sign inside an XML node as a value using element tree:

```
code: 
messageValue = f"<![CDATA[{generate_MSH(i)}"
ET.SubElement(root, "Message", MsgID="1").text = messageValue
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")
output: <Message MsgID="1">&lt;![CDATA[MSH|^~\&amp;|PATHL7
required output <Message MsgID="1"><![CDATA[MSH|^~\&;|PATHL7
```

The output to the XML file does not print < or & instead it prints < and &amp instead.

Comment: Curious, why aren't you generating a CDATA node and instead writing your own?

Comment: didn't know you could do that. looking into it. thanks!